# Simplest way to deploy a monolith with Kafka?

Tags: jhipster

If I have a JHipster monolith that also depends on Kafka, what is the easiest way to deploy everything to AWS/Azure for example ?

Comment: Please separate your two questions into individual posts

Comment: AWS: build a docker image and release it on ECS (or beanstalk might be easier), for Kafka there is a managed service: MSK

https://aws.amazon.com/msk/